# FloatingActionButton is not changing colour

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) which is pretty awesome for implementing floating action button with customized menu and many other stuffs.

But while using this library I'm facing trouble with changing the color of the `FloatingActionButton` inside a `FloatingActionMenu`. I tried putting `fab:manu_colorNormal` as a property of the `FloatingActionButton`, but it seems it has no effect and showing the default colour.

Here's the layout I'm using. Note that, I've used     `xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. It was suggested somewhere to check if the `xmlns:fab` is pointed to `apk/res-auto`. I set that properly, but yet no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/fab_close_background"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/fab_close_background_pressed"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="@color/fab_close_background_ripple">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/fab_delete_background"
            fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/fab_delete_background_pressed"
            fab:menu_colorRipple="@color/fab_delete_background_ripple" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** I could change the colour of the `FloatingActionMenu` button successfully. `menu_colorNormal` works perfectly for the close button in my layout.

Here's how it looks like in my application. Red is the default colour which I'm trying to change. The issue is [reported here in Github](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/issues/279).

[image: Floating action menu along with mini buttons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `fab:menu_colorNormal` to `fab:fab_colorNormal` in `FloatingActionButton`

> **fab:menu_colorNormal** is used to set the color of menu icon and
>   **fab:fab_colorNormal** is used to set the color of floating action
>   button.

[See the doc here.](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

Use following code:

```
 <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu_green"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_star"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#43A047"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#2E7D32"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#1B5E20"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="2"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
            fab:fab_label="Menu item 1"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#43A047"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#2E7D32"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#1B5E20" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Comment: Do you guys know, how to add background for text of fab? And how to change color of this text? To be different from fab color

Comment: Unable to customize colors. Has done everything. Even in design pane, it shows the green color but the app when installed , shows same default red color. Please help!!